# Clustering elements in a book page

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a book page that looks like this one:

[image]

Now, for every word i know the position of the surrounding rectangle.

I tried to use K-means from sklearn.cluster in order to obtain the paragraphs in the page, like this:

[image]

But the algorithms fails in obtaining the paragraphs and the major problems is that K-Means doesn't allow me to add constraints to the clustering.

Can you help me with an idea on how to get the paragraphs, titles, from this page considering that i know the position of the words, the font, and the size?

Answer (score 1):

K-means works well if clusters have the same size. In particular, it assumes clusters are best represented by the *mean*, and can be split halfway between two means. Last but not least, it assumes you know k beforehand.

These assumptions do not hold on your data. Assuming you have paragraphs of length 10 lines, 2 lines, 10 lines, then the middle "cluster" will contain some lines of the neighboring clusters.

Do not use an out of the box approach, but design an optimized algorithm for your problem. E.g. split at short lines.

Also, "segmentation" will be a more appropriate search term than "clustering".